# SELECT MAX() and corresponding field in the same row

Tags: mysql, sql, max

Here's my table A

```
orderID groupID   nameID
1       grade A   foo
2       grade A   bar
3       grade A   rain
1       grade B   rain
2       grade B   foo
3       grade B   bar
1       grade C   rain
2       grade C   bar
3       grade C   foo
```

Desired result:

```
rain
bar
foo
```

I need `nameID` of `max(orderID)` from each grade. I can get right `orderID` from each grade, but `nameID` always stays as the first.

Thanks a Lot!

---

Praveen gave the right query! Extra question under his answer

Answer (score 3):

**edit:** I just fixed a mistake in my answer.

You are looking for something quite like:

```
select
  orderID,
  groupID,
  nameID
from
  A
where
  concat(orderID,'-',groupId) in (select concat(max(orderID),'-',groupId) from A group by groupID)
```

**edit:** in regards to the extra question:
To put the list in order of nameId, just add to the query:

```
order by
  nameID
```

Comment: Tnx for the sqlfiddle. Here is the fiddle after the edit: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c38d7/2/0

Answer (score 2):

Here is an appropriate query, using a correlated subquery:

```
select orderID, groupID, nameID
from A
where orderId = (select max(OrderId) from A a2 where A.groupId = a2.groupId);
```

If you want to do this with aggregation, you can use the `group_concat()`/`substring_index()` trick:

```
SELECT max(orderID) as orderID, groupId,
       substring_index(group_concat(nameId order by orderId desc), ',', 1) as nameID
FROM A
GROUP BY groupID;
```

Comment: Ah, I see it now... orderId isn't unique. I'll try to fix my answer. Next time please leave me a comment with the downvote.

Comment: @nl-x . . . I didn't downvote you.  I've given up on downvoting.  Usually, I just leave comments.  In fact, this answer was downvoted even though it is correct as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM (select
  max(`orderID`) as maxID, `groupID`, `nameID`
from
  Table1
GROUP BY `groupID`, `nameID`
ORDER BY maxID desc) abc
GROUP BY GROUPID
```

**[Fiddle With my test data](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e94e8f/5)**

**[Fiddle with your data](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afdc6/1)**

Comment: how do I put list in order of nameID number? is therese three 'foo', like to get 3, foo.

Comment: I don't think this will always return the max. You assume the second Group By will always take the top entry of a group. But I don't think this behavior is guaranteed.

Comment: @user2689375 Sorry. I didnt get you. Can u provide expected result?